# R function for Matrix Multiplication and Addition

Tags: r, svd, matrix-decomposition, function

After performing SVD on a matrix, I would like to create a function (I'm not good with functions in R yet) that creates a reduced matrix per my specified n-value.

For instance, here is the R code for what I have now.

```
scores = c(3,1,1,-1,3,1)
Mat = matrix(scores, nrow=2)
svd = svd(Mat)
```

Now, to go from the matrix factorization to the original matrix, via brute force and ignorance, the following works.

```
score1 = svd$u[,1] %*% t(svd$v[,1]) * svd$d[1]
    score2 = svd$u[,2] %*% t(svd$v[,2]) * svd$d[2]

z = score1 + score2
z

    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    1    3
[2,]    1   -1    1
```

Going forward, I want to be able to do this on a large matrix and would like to be able to specify the number of factors.  So, instead of summing scores 1:n, I want a function to do that for me.

Comment: This sounds like more of a programming question than a statistics question.

Comment: This is one for Stackoverflow. Nevertheless, here's the function: `reconstruct <- function(m, f=1){ s <- svd(m); s$u[,1:f] %*% diag(s$d[1:f], f, f) %*% t(s$v[,1:f]) }`

Comment: Usage: `reconstruct(Mat, 1)` for a rank 1 reconstruction. `reconstruct(Mat, 2)` for a complete recovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot you just wrap your matrix arithmetic in a small function of your own?

```
recover_matrix_from_svd <- function(svd) {
    score <- 0
    for(i in 1:ncol(svd$u)) {
    score <- score + svd$u[,i] %*% t(svd$v[,i]) * svd$d[i]
    }
    score
}
```

alternatively, the `diag` function is very useful for this.  Using it results in a much clearer computation:

```
recover_matrix_from_svd <- function(svd) {
    svd$u %*% diag(svd$d) %*% t(svd$v)
}
```

Comment: and the second approach is shown in the examples section of `help("svd")`.

Comment: Many thanks, this worked perfectly.  I also tweaked it to do for(i in 1:n), where I can specify whatever n moves me.